# How to check null and implement logic based on that in JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, null

I have `parseNotAvailable` function that based on version have some logic, so i have `penalties` that has coming as version 2 but i need to have logic same as version 1, So i tried to pass as null to get 0 but its not working and throwing error.

Any better approach to achieve above task ?

main.js

```
let newPrice = {
          copayEmployer: parseNotAvailable('N/A', 1),
          penalties: parseNotAvailable('N/A', null),
          secondaryClaimNumber: parseNotAvailable('N/A',2)
        };

    function parseNotAvailable(value, version) {
      if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && (version || version === 1)) {
        return 0;
      } else if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && version === 2) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return parseFloat(value);
      }
    };



    // console.log(parseNotAvailable('N/A', 1));
    console.log(newPrice);
```

expected Result

```
{ copayEmployer: 0, penalties: 0, secondaryClaimNumber: null }
```

with above code its returning

```
{ copayEmployer: 0, penalties: NaN, secondaryClaimNumber: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `parseNotAvailable('N/A', null)` version is `null` and does not pass `if` statements na goes to else statement  `return parseFloat(value);`

In `parseNotAvailable('N/A', 2)` version is `2` and it pass  first if statements`... ||(value || value === 1)` and  `return 0;`

You have wrong assertion `if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && (version || version === 1))` it should be `if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && (!version || version === 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You're code is flowing to the `else` block and trying attempting to `parseInt('N/A')`, which obviously is `NaN`. You may want to rethink your conditions there. I added a simple `isNaN` check to your code as you can see:

```js
try {
  let newPrice = {
    copayEmployer: parseNotAvailable('N/A', 1),
    penalties: parseNotAvailable('N/A', null),
    secondaryClaimNumber: parseNotAvailable('N/A', 2)
  };
  console.log(newPrice);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}


function parseNotAvailable(value, version) {
  if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && (version || version === 1)) {
    return 0;
  } else if ((value === 'N/A' || value === 'n/a') && version === 2) {
    return null;
  } else {
    //Do a check here for NaN value - this probably isnt needed if you straigten out your flow control conditions
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      throw `${value} is NaN`;
    }
    return parseFloat(value);
  }
};
```